# Textbook on the theory of definitions

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-language

I was wondering if some of you have a recommendation for a textbook with some good philosophy on (or some theory of) definitions, or at least some ruminations on what constitutes a good definition of a term.

It's ok if the book is about a more general subject.

Comment: You can start with SEP's entry on [Definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yeah, I've read the entry already. Very interesting.

Comment: IMO it is hard to find a full book dedicated to the topic... too narrow.

Comment: Isn't it actually intellectually interesting why so few textbooks dedicated to the topic of definition which seems of first fundamental importance to every other topic?...

Comment: @DoubleKnot ikr? while reading Tankut's recomendations the authors he listed lament the same thing: "There is, alas,
hardly any literature on this topic. The discussion will therefore be
preliminary, too elementary, and imperfectly plain." Belnap.

Comment: I only read few philosopher's books and don't know any of the books listed there. If pressed on me to guess why some author said so, I'll guess due to wellknown infinite regress dilemma in epistemology, any definition only acts as a temporary foundation which needs further justification, or acts like Kant's axiom-like space and time notion, but modern physics indicates spacetime may be just relational illusion not real substance as required foundation by classic scholastic philosophy. Most modern trend seems focus definitions squarely back on pure phenomena within our perceived world only...

Comment: i don't think you necessarily need to trouble the modern concepts of spacetime in order to lay down some philosophical musings on what constitutes a "good" definition.

Comment: I can only say from my perspective we intuitively know "definition" is a kind of relevant properties bundling (binding) about the perceived or conceived subject. As for the "good" ones, it has to include as much as possible of all such bindings, my point above is it's easier said than done. In an ideal world, if everyone holds the same "complete" definition of a subject, then just let's calculate and there'll simply be no disputes or disagreements at all...

Comment: I really REALLY don't think this is right.

Comment: That's all right and totally fine as per my own view above. Wish you may report back your distillation, or opinion or any conclusion here again after you finished reading those textbooks or from your own search endeavor. I really enjoy reading opposite ideas...

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, there is, regrettably, no textbook-style source on the theory of definition. However, *Definitions and Definability: Philosophical Perspectives* (edited by J. H. Fetzer et al, Springer, Synthese Library, 1991) is quite accessible to the novice and [freely available from Springer](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-011-3346-3).

As it is for many topics in philosophy, I would recommend you to read about the historical development of the notion as a smooth way to have a grip on it. In this regard, *Essays on Definition* (edited by J. C. Sager with an introduction by A. Rey, John Benjamins Publishing Company, 2000) and *Definition in Greek Philosophy* (edited by D. Charles, Oxford University Press, 2010) can be helpful.

N. Belnap's 1993 article "On Rigorous Definitions" (*Philosophical Studies* 72, pp. 115-146) is informative about recent discussions. There is also R. Robinson's *Definition* (Clarendon Press, 1950); however, it may remain too outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps these may help.

"The Meaning of Meaning: A Study of the Influence of Language Upon Thought and of the Science of Symbolism By Charles Kay Ogden, Ivor Armstrong Richards, Bronislaw Malinowski, Francis Graham Crookshank, John Percival Postgate · 1923"

Free edition here:

https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Meaning_of_Meaning/w099AAAAMAAJ?hl=en

Another field to look into would be Semiotics.

"Signs: An Introduction to Semiotics
By Thomas Albert Sebeok · 2001"

https://www.google.com/books/edition/Signs/pCbFvfHFitYC?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

The most influential philosophical theory of definitions probably still is Russell's [On Denoting](https://users.drew.edu/jlenz/br-on-denoting.html). A few years ago there was a [special issue](https://academic.oup.com/mind/issue/114/456) of the journal Mind, dedicated to the centenary of that paper. I would check that out.